# Splitting String from Arraylist (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, split, arrays

FIXED! Thanks everyone!

Okay, so I am not sure why this is giving me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException..

al is an arraylist holding values such as:

```
2,6,m
1,7,w   
5,3,c   
0,4,w
1,6,w
2,3,w
1,5,w
```

Here is where I am trying to get each arraylist index, split it into: row, col, letter.
It is saying that temp[2] is outofbounds. Why? I mean the split method should make 3 parts, 0,1, and 2. So why is 2 giving me fits. I ran some tests and it also gave outofbounds for temp[0] and temp[1] calls.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        String[] temp = al.get(i).toString().split(",");
        System.out.println(temp.length);
        System.out.println(temp[1]);
        if (temp[2].equals("m")) {
            boardTiles[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])].setIcon(mousetile);
            boardTiles[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])].putClientProperty("mouse", true);
        }
        if (temp[2].equals("c")) {
            boardTiles[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])].setIcon(cheesetile);
            boardTiles[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])].putClientProperty("cheese", true);
        }
        if (temp[2].equals("w")) {
            boardTiles[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])].setIcon(metalwall);
            boardTiles[Integer.parseInt(temp[0])][Integer.parseInt(temp[1])].putClientProperty("wall", true);
        }
    }
```

Am I utilizing the String[] with the split method wrong or something?
Thanks,
-Austin

EDITS:

I just ran a for loop on the arraylist, all of the values are there.

boardTiles[x][x] is a 2d array of JButtons.

Exception is occuring at index: 1.

the .length is showing is 1 as well.

Comment: please show definition of `boardTiles`

Comment: what Index is the exception happening at?

Comment: Are you sure you inputs are always like the example inputs you gave above? Try printing out the input each time to see which input is giving you the error.

Comment: What does `temp.length` show before you get the exception? It looks like one of your strings doesn't have the right format.

Comment: I think your issue is at temp[1], when you try to print it.  Since al.get(i) is returning one string, your temp[1] doesn't exist. EDIT: nm I see the split there.

Comment: @YiussefG. Added edits and updates

Comment: the exception is occurring at index = 1 with length = 1. The last valid index for an array is length-1 (in this case 0) so you're going out of bounds at index 1.

Comment: @Austin: `.length` should show 3, right? but is showing 1.

Comment: @YiussefG. Wow..I feel stupid, I forgot the very first value in the arraylist is a single number specifying the board size, since its only 1 number the temp.split went to a size of 1. Haha, so sorry about this silly mistake! Thanks though!

Comment: @Austin: if you are reading your input from a file: are there some empty lines?

Comment: @juergend read comment above to YiussefG, thanks for the help again guys. Silly mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boardTiles` probably doesn't have the size of some values defined in your input array.

Comment: @jeurgend can't be, before I do this part it runs a boardbuilder method which displays fine in the JFrame. So that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do a print of al.get(i) and double check that it is indeed a comma separated string of values.